# How to regex-match a comma delimited list containing AWS Security Group IDs?

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-security-group

How can I match a comma delimited list which could be either empty or AWS Security Group Ids e.g. `sg-qwe12345,sg-543234aewrfs,sg-12eqwrwer,sg-gjkkh12435`?

I tried `(^$|sg-[0-9a-z]+\,|sg-[0-9a-z]+)(?<!\,)$` in the allowed pattern in the cloudformation template but when I am entering a comma at the end and deploy stack the stack creation process start and fails.

Ideally, it should stop and ask me to check as `(?<!\,)$` in allowed pattern should not allow the comma at the end.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense to think about how a "list" is defined:

- Nothing
- 1 item
- Several items, which is 1 item followed by a "delimiter" and more items

or, more formally:

```
list  = '' | items
items = item | item ',' items
item  = 'sg-' ident
ident = [0-9a-z]+
```

As a regex, this might look like:

```
^(sg-[0-9a-z]+(,sg-[0-9a-z]+)*)?$
```

---

But since you are using AWS CloudFormation, why not choose an appropriate type, such as [CommaDelimitedList](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html)? With this type, the regex could be greatly simplified to just `^(sg-[0-9a-z]+)$`; the type itself takes care of the rest (comma-handling).

From the docs:

> `AllowedPattern`: […]. When applied to a parameter of type `CommaDelimitedList`, the pattern must match each value in the list.

> `CommaDelimitedList`: An array of literal strings that are separated by commas. The total number of strings should be one more than the total number of commas. Also, each member string is space trimmed.
>
> For example, users could specify `"test,dev,prod"`, and a `Ref` would result in `["test","dev","prod"]`.

Did you provide `ConstraintDescription` or a `Default` value?

Comment: I have tried the ^(sg-[0-9a-z]+(,sg-[0-9a-z]+)*)?$ and my aws cloudformation is proceeding without thorwing message to correct the comma delimited list if the pattern is not correct

Comment: @ParasJain what was your input? I don't see how this pattern could match anything else, but I'm happy to correct if there are some additional, unmentioned rules

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is different flavors of regex (e.g. BRE vs ERE) and meta characters such as `(`, `)`, `+`, and `?` need to be escaped/toggled first

Comment: @ParasJain See demo: https://regex101.com/r/FUF9HT/2 – please explain which input did not work for you

Comment: When I am entering sg-789,, it should throw before deploying the stack. 
As we have applied the AllowedPatterns: ^(sg-[0-9a-z]+(,sg-[0-9a-z]+)*)?$ but it is not throwing error and failing during the runtime or deploying stating the last item of the list which is ",," is causing the error. I think the regex you provided is correct but the issue is with some aws cloudformation.

Comment: @ParasJain see updated answer, why not use `CommaDelimitedList` type over `String`?

Comment: I am using CommaDelimited list only

Comment: @ParasJain if you read the docs, you will find it says that the regex applies to _each item_ in the list, not the list itself.

Comment: @ParasJain I still think the original question "write a regex for a comma-delimited list of "sg-" strings" is properly and fully answered.